# Android Studio: project does not use the Gradle build system after pushing to Github

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github, android-studio

Recently, my Android project is being told that it does not use the Gradle build system. Also, for some reason, the only folder listed within my project is the java folder, which contains R, the buildconfig, and the auto-generated manifest used by the IDE, but it doesn't contain the actual app files, located in the "app" folder. The "app" folder exists, but is not listed in the app. Furthermore, I am unable to drag and drop the folder into the hierarchy listed in Android Studio. Also, there's a build.gradle that isn't listed.

The app built fine before, and the only change I can tell is that I have pushed a newer version to Github after importing the entire thing from Eclipse. It built fine with the gradle build system after importing from Eclipse. I have just tried to commit the build.gradle into the app, which was unversioned before. The problem is that the project still claims to not use the gradle build system.

Comment: I had some similar problem with Android studio 1.5. I cloned the project again from my git repo (bitbucket) and my problem was solved.